# Dashboard - empty blocks are shown

Tags: 7, dashboard

I had a some blocks on the dashboard page. 
Then I created a new role with fewer permissions and wanted to show only a couple of them on the dashboard. 
I edited all blocks and restricted the access by role.

Now all the blocks with restricted content are still visible in the dashboard but they all have the "(empty)" text on it.

How can I get rid of these blocks completely ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is caused by a bug in dashboard module, and should be postet to the module's issue queue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in dashboard.module.

Quick and silly solution: disable, uninstall, enable and reconfigure again the Dashboard module. Remember: You will lose all dashboard settings you made :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find an answer on my similar question: [How to get rid of empty blocks on the dashboard?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90291/how-to-get-rid-of-empty-blocks-on-dashboard). I solved my problem by deleting the bloks directly from my database.