# Role specific dashboard block

Tags: 7, views, blocks, dashboard

I created a set of Views based blocks which will be displayed in the Dashboard's Main Content Region.But those all of them are not for the site admins. Some of them are for other roles. So I have configured those blocks' visibility settings. Added those specific roles to the "Show block for specific roles" tab. But the problem is those are being displayed in the admin dashboard as well but with no content, actually it says "empty".

Is there any way to get rid of this?

A possible duplicate but no answers in that post as well. 
[Dashboard - empty blocks are shown](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45322/dashboard-empty-blocks-are-shown)

Answer (score 1):

One way to hide the blocks completely without doing any coding is to set up your own custom dashboard using the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.  With Panels, you can override pages (such as the admin dashboard) and then add the blocks using Panels.  The advantage of this approach is that you can use the **Visibility conditions** feature of Panels to only show the block for certain roles, which will completely hide the block rather than showing an empty version.

The disadvantage of this approach is that this might be overkill if this is all you need to do.