# How to get rid of empty blocks on the dashboard?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, dashboard

I created a View called *Recent comments* and added a block to my dashboard. Afterwards, I deleted the View, which results in an empty block on my dashboard

[image: Empty block]

and the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: recent-comments-block in
>   dashboard_page_build() (line 192 of
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\modules\dashboard\dashboard.module).

I tried to drag the empty block away after clicking *Customize dashboard*, but every time I hit *Done*, it is displayed again. Clearing caches did not help either.

What should I do to get rid of the empty block?

Comment: I had the same problem. If you customize it via the `admin/dashboard/configure` page instead of the _Customize dashboard_ button, it should not appear again.(You should first delete the empty blocks from database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a long-standing issue with dashboard blocks. See the discussion, and several patches, here: https://drupal.org/node/936798

I haven't tried any of these patches myself.

If you just want to get rid of the error, I believe you can delete inactive blocks in the database directly, as described here: https://drupal.org/node/1202500

The gist is that you look for and remove blocks in the block table where region = dashboard_inactive

Answer (score 1):

**Fast Solution:**

1. Create a new block view with the same machine name (recent-comments)
2. Disable the block from dashboard configuration page `admin/dashboard/configure` - make sure to set the region to none.
3. Delete the created block view in step 1

**Another solution:**

Delete the deleted block (recent-comments-block) from database directly

```
DELETE FROM `block` WHERE `delta` like 'recent-comments-block';
```